# How to originate multiple calls in freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I have tried to originate a call from cli, My call file will hit two Java applications at a time so that they starts communicating to each other. Now My requirement is to originate multiple calls at once so that multiple threads run at same time. and Thus I can test the load etc. I have tried following for originating single call It works fine.

```
originate loopback/1234/default &bridge({ignore_early_media=true}sofia/internal/1789@XX.XX.XX.XX)
```

The above file can only be executed once, If I run it in a loop even then only one call is invoked. Please suggest me some way how to originate more number of calls in freeswitch

Answer (score 1):

Your code is getting stuck waiting for the result -- 'api' commands are blocking

If you execute this as 'bgapi originate....' then it will be a background execution (bg) and be non-blocking -- it will return a job uuid, and let you execute more commands.

See:

- http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_Socket_Library#bgapi
- http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_Socket#bgapi

Answer (score 0):

bgapi returns only Job-UUID, but not call uuid. what to do next?

Comment: you can set set your custom uuid and pass it to originate command @dragonfly